# LoadFromFile with Unicode data

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe

My input file(f) has some Unicode (Swedish) that isn't being read correctly.

Neither of these approaches works, although they give different results:

```
  LoadFromFile(f);
```

or

```
  LoadFromFile(f,TEncoding.GetEncoding(GetOEMCP));
```

I'm using Delphi XE

How can I LoadFromFile some Unicode data....also how do I subsequently SaveToFile?  Thanks

Comment: What is the encoding of the file?

Comment: Use `TEncoding.Default` instead of `TEncoding.GetEncoding(GetOemCP)`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In order to load a Unicode text file you need to know its encoding. If the file has a Byte Order Mark (BOM), then you can simply call `LoadFromFile(FileName)` and the RTL will use the BOM to determine the encoding.

If the file does not have a BOM then you need to explicitly specify the encoding, e.g.

```
LoadFromFile(FileName, TEncoding.UTF8);
LoadFromFile(FileName, TEncoding.Unicode);//UTF-16 LE
LoadFromFile(FileName, TEncoding.BigEndianUnicode);//UTF-16 BE
```

For some reason, unknown to me, there is no built in support for UTF-32, but if you had such a file then it would be easy enough to add a `TEncoding` instance to handle that.

Comment: Determining the encoding of a file seems to be problematic. It appears that some of the UTF8 files do not have a BOM. This appears to work:

InputData.LoadFromFile(f,TEncoding.UTF8);
if InputData.count=0 then
  InputData.LoadFromFile(f);

Is there a better approach. I know this solution isn't very elegant.

Comment: Read the first few bytes and check against the known BOMs. If there is no BOM then you have to know the encoding. You can make a good guess but it's a bit hit and miss.

Comment: Is there a way to find out what encoding a file has, before calling LoadFromFile ?

Comment: @delphirules In general, no

Comment: But there are online services that claims to identify any file's encoding, how they do it ?

Comment: @delphirules They don't succeed reliably. It's possible to have a single file that is valid when interpreted in multiple files. So whilst you can develop algos that would predict which of the possible valid encodings is the most likely, probablistic algos are as good as you can get.

Answer (score 7):

I assume that you mean 'UTF-8' when you say 'Unicode'.

If you know that the file is UTF-8, then do

```
LoadFromFile(f, TEncoding.UTF8).
```

To save:

```
SaveToFile(f, TEncoding.UTF8);
```

(The `GetOEMCP` WinAPI function is for old 255-character character sets.)